# Highcharts visualize, style series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts.visualize to draw the graph from a table containing the data.

You can test my working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/S2XM8/1/

I have two questions:

1. I want to have a separate styling for my "Additional value". How do I go about it?
2. Can I add data for the X-axis via the javascript? For example if I need to fill in the gap between 2014-05-27 and 2014-05-25 in the table.

   ```
   Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options, tableClass) {
       // the categories
       options.xAxis.categories = [];
       $('tbody th', table).each( function () {
           options.xAxis.categories.push(this.innerHTML);
       });

       // the data series
       options.series = [];
       $('tr', table).each( function (i) {
           var tr = this;
           $('.graph', tr).each( function (j) {
               if (i === 0) { // get the name and init the series
                   options.series[j] = {
                       name: this.innerHTML,
                       data: []
                   };
               } else { // add values
                   options.series[j].data.push(parseFloat(this.innerHTML));
                   console.log(this.innerHTML);
               }
           });
       });

       options.title = { text: 'Some graph' };

       $('#' + tableClass + '-graph').highcharts(options);
   };

   var tableNumber = document.getElementById('rank-table'),

   options = {
       chart: {
           zoomType: 'x'
       },
       xAxis: {
           tickInterval: 30,
           reversed: true,
           labels: {
               rotation: 45
           },
           type: 'datetime',
           dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
               month: '%e. %b',
               year: '%b'
           }
       },
       yAxis: {
           title: {
               text: 'Rank'
           },
           min: 1,
           reversed: true
       },
       legend: {
           layout: 'vertical',
           align: 'middle',
           verticalAlign: 'bottom',
           borderWidth: 0
       }
   };

   Highcharts.visualize(tableNumber, options, 'number');
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both things are possible, but require to modify visualize method, see: http://jsfiddle.net/S2XM8/4/

1. You can set series options in a chart and then merge with data:

   ```
   series: [{
       // nothing special
   }, {
      type: 'column' // set series type for example
   }]
   ```

   And merging:

   ```
               options.series[j] = options.series[j] || {};
               options.series[j].name = this.innerHTML,
               options.series[j].data = [];
   ```
2. Check parsed value before passing as point value:

   ```
               var value = parseFloat(this.innerHTML);

               if(isNaN(value)) { //null value - produces NaN when parsing
                   options.series[j].data.push(10);
               } else {
                   options.series[j].data.push(value); // push value to the series
               }
   ```